# Memory upgrade for Toshiba P20 S203?

Tags: laptop, memory

I've had an offer of a 256MB PC2700 SODIMM, apparently from an iBook, to upgrade a Toshiba laptop. Is that suitable? I've seen "DDR 266 SODIMM" on sale as the official upgrade memory.

How in general should I work this out? I've long since lost track of what memory goes with what system.

Comment: I can't comment due to my recent arrival and hence low Rep, Shevek is correct.
My tuppence:
If you go to cruical it will give you full details of the RAM including the maximum ammount of memory that your system will handle, this will no doubt influence your decision.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Satellite P20 then according to [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=Satellite%20P20%20Series) 200-pin SODIMM DDR PC2700 is the correct RAM for it